# While selecting a drop down list, it should display the values of a column from a table .. How to achieve that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

First I have created a table `Grocery_Branch` and then I inserted the values:

```
CREATE TABLE Grocery_Branch
(Grocery_Branch_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Grocery_Branch_Name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Grocery_Branch_Address VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Grocery_Phone_No VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
 )

INSERT INTO Grocery_Branch (Grocery_Branch_Name,Grocery_Branch_Address,Grocery_Phone_No)
VALUES('Inala','39 Lavender Street, Inala QLD 4077','0423957193')
INSERT INTO Grocery_Branch (Grocery_Branch_Name,Grocery_Branch_Address,Grocery_Phone_No)
VALUES('Richlands','1 Progress Road, Richlands QLD 4077','0423957192')
INSERT INTO Grocery_Branch (Grocery_Branch_Name,Grocery_Branch_Address,Grocery_Phone_No)
VALUES ('Forest Lake','235 Forest Lake Boulevard, Forest Lake QLD 4078','0423957191')
```

Then I created Administrator Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Administrator
(Administrator_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Administrator_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Administrator_Username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Administrator_Password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Administrator_Phone_No VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Administrator_Email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Grocery_Branch_No INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Grocery_Branch(Grocery_Branch_No)
 )
```

Then I created a stored procedure for Admin Registration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AdminRegistration

@AdministratorName VARCHAR(50),
@AdministratorUsername VARCHAR(30),
@AdministratorPassword VARCHAR(30),
@AdministratorPhoneNo VARCHAR(20),
@AdministratorEmail VARCHAR(30),
@GroceryBranchName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Administrator(Administrator_Name,Administrator_Username,Administrator_Password,Administrator_Phone_No,Administrator_Email,Grocery_Branch_No)
SELECT @AdministratorName,@AdministratorUsername,@AdministratorPassword, @AdministratorPhoneNo,@AdministratorEmail,(SELECT Grocery_Branch_No FROM Grocery_Branch WHERE Grocery_Branch_Name = @GroceryBranchName)
END
```

Then this is what I have done in `SignUp.aspx`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>
        <strong>SIGN UP</strong></p>
        <p>
            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Alphabets only" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\s]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            Username:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>           
        </p>
        <p>
            Password:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>           
        </p>
        <p>
            Phone No:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Numbers only" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" />           
        </p>
        <p>
            Email:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="Email should have @ and .com" ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Select Branch:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Please select a branch"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Register" Text="Register" />
        </p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then this is what I have done in `SignUp.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Grocery_Demo
{
    public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Register(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CS;
            CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AdminRegistration", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministrationName", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministrationUsername", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministrationPassword", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministrationPhoneNo", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdministrationEmail", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox("You are registered successfully");
            Session["Username"] = TextBox2.Text;
            Session["Password"] = TextBox3.Text;
            Response.Redirect("AdminHomepage.aspx");
            con.Close();
        }

        public void MessageBox(string message)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "MessageBox", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + message + "')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the `SignUp.aspx` page
It is displaying admin form the way I wanted to.

The issue is with "Select Branch" drop down list.

What I want to achieve is that when I click on the drop down list, it is supposed to show the list of values of `Grocery_Branch_Name` column from `Grocery_Branch` table.
Instead, the drop down list is empty when I'm clicking on it.

I couldn't figure out where is the mistake I'm making.
The mistake can be in my `.cs` or `.aspx` or Stored Procedure.

If there is any error in my syntax logic in my Stored Procedure or `.aspx` or `.cs`, then it would be really helpful if the right syntax solution is provided.

Comment: The dropdownlist isn't bound to any datasource, is it? This would explain why it is empty. Or do you attach a datasource in the code behind and forgot to post that relevant code?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  No the drop down list doesn't have any datasource.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have not provided any data to your drop down list. In Web Forms this is usually done in two ways:

**1. Using a data source object**

In this case you should add this object in your .aspx page:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="[dataSourceID]" runat="server" 
   SelectMethod=" " 
   TypeName=" " 
   DataObjectTypeName=" ">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) on how to properly fill in the ObjectDataSource properties.

Then add the following properties to your DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="[dataSourceID]"
   DataTextField="Grocery_Branch_Name"
   DataValueField="Grocery_Branch_No">
```

The rest is for you to write the method to retrive the data.

**2. Manually feeding the list in Page_Load event handler**

```
If (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   List<GroceryBranch> allGroceryBranches = GetAllGroceryBranchesFromDB();
   DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
   DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(allGroceryBranches
    .Select(b=> new ListItem(b.Grocery_Branch_Name, b.Grocery_Branch_No))
}
```

But you are still missing the mechanism from retrieving the data from your database.

Comment: I have fixed it now ... Now it's working ... You may refer to my Answer section to have a look at the code

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem already.
This is what I did in SignUp.aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems ="true" ID ="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Grocery_Branch_Name" DataValueField="Grocery_Branch_Name">
             <Items>
             <asp:ListItem Value="" >Select a Branch</asp:ListItem>
             </Items>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Grocery_DemoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Grocery_Branch_Name] FROM [Grocery_Branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Branch is not selected"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```